# ffmpeg: messed up nvidia devices

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia

IDs `hwaccel_device` for `ffmpeg` do not match to `nvidia-smi`.
When I specifie `hwaccel_devices 0`, then `nvidia-smi` shows load device 1 and vice versa.

```
# ffmpeg -vsync 0 -i sb.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc -gpu list -f null –
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-n4.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
...
...
[h264_nvenc @ 0x55d8a307ab80] [ GPU #0 - < GeForce GTX 1080 Ti > has Compute SM 6.1 ]
[h264_nvenc @ 0x55d8a307ab80] [ GPU #1 - < GeForce GTX 1080 > has Compute SM 6.1 ]
```

and

```
# nvidia-smi -L
GPU 0: GeForce GTX 1080 (UUID: GPU-fc961076-46b5-88f5-b760-0b7b7eaa58b1)
GPU 1: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti (UUID: GPU-cea02757-0c19-6e12-7a83-290cef135f7e)
```

I see this for the first time, before they always coincided.
Is it possible to syncrhonize this?

Answer (score 0):

I found!
It need to set var

```
CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID
```

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars